# Building SWIG generated file into DLL in windows

Tags: java, c++, c, swig

i have read the swig tutorial and it does this :

```
$ swig -java example.i
$ gcc -c example_wrap.c  -I/usr/java/include -I/usr/java/include/solaris
$ ld -G example_wrap.o  -o libexample.so
```

i can do the first command , but the next two commands cant be executed, because i dont have gcc, however i do have Microsoft visual studio express 2013, but i cant find any tutorial using MSE2013 to build the dll file.
I am running W7 64bit.Also i am building from c++ to java.

Does anyone have any idea how to generate the library file? so i can do

```
public class runme {
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("example");
  }

  public static void main(String argv[]) {
    System.out.println(example.fact(4));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually build Python wrappers, but it should be something like:

```
cl /LD /Feexample.dll /IC:\jdk1.3\include /IC:\jdk1.3\include\win32 example_wrap.c
```

`/LD` generates a DLL, `/Fe` sets the output filename, `/I` adds include paths.

There is also: http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Java_visual_studio